# Rails: Passing variables via remote link to partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to achieve a bare image gallery in that I present the user with a list of thumbnails and if he clicks one of it, a partial with the normal version of it should refresh a container on the page.

As of now I only can get to work a solution with one other picture because I then can use the definite `image.last` element in the partial to access its values.

I read a lot on how to pass variables to partials, especially on this site. I tried locals - with no luck. I read that there might be a solution with `params.merge()` but it is vulnerable to xss. I at least tried to find a solution with params.merge on my dev environment but failed.

This is my actual solution. On the `show` view I use:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col s12" id="ngGallery">
  <h2 class="game-subheading"><%= @gallery.images.first.title %></h2>
  <img src="<%= @gallery.images.first.image %>" class="responsive-img">
  <p><%= @gallery.images.first.desc %></p>
 </div>
</div>

<table>
 <tr>
  <% @gallery.images.each do |i| %>
  <td><%= link_to image_tag(i.image_url(:preview)), @gallery, :remote => true %></td>
  <% end %>
 </tr>
</table>
```

That table shows clickable thumbnails and it is responsive as it offers horizontal scrolling on small viewports. The above `#ngGallery` container is the one I want to change.

My `show` method in the controller makes sure that it responds to a js via a partial.

```
def show
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
 end
end
```

The `show.js.erb` contains:

```
$('#ngGallery').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'ngGallery') %>");
```

In that file I tried out locals like `:locals=>{:picture=>"#{i.id}"}` but when I wanted to use them in the `ngGallery`-partial I had no luck. Server responded with 500 internal error in the browser.

The partial itself contains:

```
<h2 class="game-subheading"><%= @gallery.images.last.title %></h2>
<img src="<%= @gallery.images.last.image %>" class="responsive-img">
<p><%= @gallery.images.last.title %></p>
```

As I said. This way it works for "one" click of the user but I want to iterate over the whole gallery which consists of separate image files. A gallery has many images and an image belongs to a gallery. This is my association.

With the locals approach I tried using things like `<%= @gallery.images.find_by(id: :picture).title %>` but it did not work.

Comment: In your show mehtod define `@image = Gallery.find(params[:id])` and in your view  use `$('#ngGallery').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'ngGallery', :locals => {image => @image}) %>")`

Comment: @Pardeep Saini If I understand your advice the right way, it won't help me? `Gallery.find(params[:id]`) will offer an array of several images. This way I still don't know which image it is, the user clicked on. Because only this image should refresh the partial.

Comment: then you need to pass image id to your show method and pass that image to your partial.

Comment: That's what I want but all I tried did not work. As I said I tried to pass locals on but that did not work well.

Comment: try this `<td><%= link_to image_tag(i.image_url(:preview)), gallery_path(@gallery.id, image_id: image.id) , :remote => true %></td>`

Comment: By using this you will get image id in your controller.

Comment: My mistake. I did not use `Image.find` but `Gallery.find` in the controller. But now it seems to work. Thx a lot. Does your solution have any caveats? Especially concerning security? :) Because I want to use it on a community site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to image_tag(i.image_url(:preview)), gallery_path(@gallery.id, image_id: image.id) , :remote => true %></td>
```

This only show the image id , when you try inspect element on your browser. i think that not a big deal.

Comment: Together with the comments above I voted up I was able to achieve my image gallery. Thx a lot. :)